# Discord bot not starting, keeps loading before the ready! message shows on terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Up until about an hour ago, my bot worked fine, and now when I try to start it, it keeps loading before the ready! message comes up. I didn't change the code at all before this error and not sure what's wrong.

Here's my code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./myconfig10.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const request = require('request');
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
const embedAuthor = ('This bot was made by <my discord name>')
const servers = client.guilds.cache.size


//Telling the bot where to look for the commands
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

//Once the bot is up and running, display 'Ready' in the console
client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
    




//Seeing if the message starts with the prefix
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

//Telling the bot what arguments are
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/)
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

//Checking to see if the command you sent is one of the commands in the commands folder 
    if (!client.commands.has(commandName)) return;
    console.log(`Collected 1 Item, ${message}`)

    const command = client.commands.get(commandName);

//Try to execute the command.
    try {
        command.execute(message, args);
    
//If there's an error, don't crash the bot. 
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        
//Sends a message on discord telling you there was an error
        message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
```

Edit: I fixed it, i had accidentally put a } after the client.login command.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @oliver su there is no error,it just keeps loading and nothing comes up

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot to end it with a `}`, is that the problem?

Comment: i do have it, i just accidentally didn't include it